# Read exact number of messages from a topic using poll

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am working with Kafka using the Python version. I have a producer which produces 'n' messages each time, and I have a consumer which must consume these messages. I want that the consumer consumes exactly a fixed number of messages 'x' if 'x' messages are available on that topic or less in the case the number of messages in the topic is less than x. I am using

```
msgs_pack = server.poll(timeout_ms=2500, max_records=x)
```

but it is not giving me the behavior that I want. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In kafka-python, you'd pass `max_poll_records` into the consumer properties, not the poll method itself.

That defaults to 500 already, and represents **up to** the max amount you'll get per poll.

Otherwise, loop over the polled records and count up to the amount you need, then process the batch and commit the offsets

Comment: I got your answer, however, what I see is that the number of messages on the topic is always less than 500 which means that probably this is not the bottleneck. The second option, if I correctly understood it, means that I actually consume the messages in the topic even if I can't at the moment I pull them from the topic. As the client is in real-time, and this consumer must then publish on other topics, do you suggest I use streams?

Comment: just to clarify, is there a primitive in the consumer which I can use to get the number of messages in the topic?

Comment: Consumers typically run an endless loop to poll. The default max amount will be **up to 500 per-poll**, as answered. If there's less, then you get all records. Otherwise, consumer will wait for new events as they are produced. You dont need "streams" (which is a Java API, not Python)... You can query for the partition "high watermarks", but since records can actively be deleted in Kafka from retention or compaction, there is no direct query for "number of current records"